# Including phpBB

Tags: php, phpbb

I installed phpBB on my localhost and can access it via localhost/myProject/board/, while my normal access path to my website would be localhost/myProject/?s=home

I want to include phpBB into my site in a way that it won't feel like a different site anymore, but behaves more like an iframe. I tried adding a board.php which just executes

```
include("viewforum.php");
```

and is accessed via localhost/myProject/?s=board. Result should be my basic .html site, with the phpBB included in the contentArea. However it doesn't work by giving errors like

```
WARNING: INCLUDE(/BOARD/COMMON.PHP): FAILED TO OPEN STREAM: NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY
```

I googled a bit and can't find a solution for this. My train of thought here is that board.php could act as a wrapper around the phpBB and include the whole stuff in my side to act like an iframe AND handle the GET parameters. For example when browsing normally in the phpBB i get URLs like

```
http://localhost/myProject/board/viewforum.php?f=2
```

This should be handled by the wrapper by wrapping the GET parameters like

```
http://localhost/myProject/?s=board&boardSite=viewforum&f=2
```

Is something like that possible without to much effort?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried something similar, but found it a lot easier to incorporate my site into phpBB using their templating system rather than trying to get the forum inside the existing site.

Comment: Is there some sort of free php Board, which offers this kind of feature?

Comment: I don't know if theres anything 'off the shelf' that offers as many features as phpBB, but its not as difficult as it may sound. Have a look at their dev wiki, theres a tutorial to help you get started here: https://wiki.phpbb.com/Tutorial.Adding_pages

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is that you may find a similar scheme theme to add to the forum and add required menu at the top by using html & css code from the main site's menu.

Well, the most easiest and worst way is to use an iframe. It would display the board in a frame inside the page. It virtually makes linking imposibble and has other negative side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a very hard time attempt to embed it like this. The application is not designed to be wrapped like this.

Your best bet is to adapt the phpBB styles to your website templates.